# c++ variadic parameter pack to a void** array

Tags: c++, c++14

I need to transform a variadic parameter pack into a c style `void**` array with each entry pointing to the address of each packed parameter.

```
template <typename ... ArgsT>
void func (ArgtsT&&... args) {
  void* pointers[sizeof...(ArgsT)];
  // Now, I want pointers[i] to be (void*)&(ith-args)
  // How do implement this?
}
```

I can use only C++14.

Answer (score 1):

Just make parameters pack expansion with getting address of objects by `&`:

```
template <typename ... ArgsT>
void func (ArgsT && ... args) 
{
  void* pointers[sizeof...(ArgsT)] = { &args... };
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/LuZ7WB)